# Can't add PCL to existing Xamarin Forms project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, prism

Brand new install of Visual Studio Pro 2017, Prism Template Pack, and Xamarin Forms.

I am trying to create my first App and things are going very well so far.  I have all the views, view models, etc. set and the app is functioning perfectly.  Now I am trying to add some more PCL projects to the solution for things like Domain or Services, etc. so I can keep all the parts separated.

I can create a Xamarin Forms PCL just fine and add all my classes, etc.  Problem comes when I try to add a reference to the Domain project from the main PCL project in the solution.  I get the "targets of pcl don't match" error message.

This is what I am using to create the new PCL project:
[image: This is what I am using to create the new PCL project:]

This is the error message I receive when trying to add the PCL project reference:
[image: This is the error message:]

What am I missing?

Here is the main PCL created with the template pack properties:
[image]

Here is the newly added PCL project properties:
[image]

PCL properties for template:
[image]

Comment: do all of your PCL projects use the same Profile?

Comment: Added 2 more pictures in original post for properties of the 2 PCL projects.

Comment: I will say that when I used the Prism Template Pack, I only chose ios and android ... why are the Windows phone targets in there.  How can I remove just the Windows targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are missing the Windows Phone & Silverlight targets in your IDE for some reason, this is a potential workaround:

Open up your `.csproj` files and make sure the `TargetFrameworkProfile` elements match up in both PCL projects.

Is it possible that you didn't install the tools for Windows Phone development when you installed Visual Studio?

Comment: Original PCL project created with the Prism pack has     <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile259</TargetFrameworkProfile>

Comment: Newly created Domain PCL project has     <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile111</TargetFrameworkProfile>

Comment: Make sure they line up, then you should be able to add the reference. See [this link](https://portablelibraryprofiles.stephencleary.com/) for a list of the PCL target frameworks. Doesn't really matter much which one you choose.

Comment: Changed the Domain project to 259 and it added just fine.

Comment: Glad to help. I'm still curious why you are missing the options in your IDE though. If anyone knows why, please add a comment or edit the answer.

Comment: Follow up question - Is there a place to default this in Visual Studio so that all new PCL projects get 259 or whatever version so you don't have to edit the file manually and change it?

Comment: According to the 'Changing targets' paragraph on [these docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx) the target framework that are set by default, depend on which ones you have selected previously. I suggest that you create a new question for this if you need more detailed information.

Comment: It seems to me that Xamarin has changed it's target profile in it's templates and the Prism Template Pack needs to be updated to stay sync'd with Xamarin.